# Xamarin Forms MVVM iOS ListView doesn't show; SelectedItem has data

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm, xamarin.ios

I followed this example https://medium.com/swlh/xamarin-forms-mvvm-how-to-work-with-sqlite-db-c-xaml-26fcae303edd

I put a breakpoint in my OnRouteSelected event handler, and e.SelectedItem has the selected object, even though the ListView doesn't display it.

Am I missing something glaring below?

Here is my code:
RoutesPage.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"> 
       
    <ContentPage.Content>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Routes}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRoute, Mode=TwoWay}" HasUnevenRows="False" SeparatorColor="Gray" ItemSelected="OnRouteSelected">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <ViewCell> 
                <ViewCell.View>
                    <Label TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding ROName}"/>
                </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>

        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

RoutesPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class RoutesPage : ContentPage
    {
        public RoutesPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var routeStore = new RouteStore(DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDb>());
            var pageService = new PageService();
            ViewModel = new RoutesPageViewModel(routeStore, pageService);
        }
        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            ViewModel.LoadDataCommand.Execute(null);

        }

        void OnRouteSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ViewModel.SelectRouteCommand.Execute(e.SelectedItem);
        }
        public RoutesPageViewModel ViewModel
        {
            get { return BindingContext as RoutesPageViewModel; }
            set { BindingContext = value; }
        }
    }
```

RoutesPageViewModel.cs The LoadData() method gets the data and adds it to the Routes Collection successfully.

```
public class RoutesPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private RouteViewModel _selectedRoute;
        private IRouteStore _routeStore;
        private IPageService _pageService;

        private bool _isDataLoaded;

        public ObservableCollection<RouteViewModel> Routes { get; private set; }
            = new ObservableCollection<RouteViewModel>();

        public RouteViewModel SelectedRoute
        {
            get { return _selectedRoute; }
            set { SetValue(ref _selectedRoute, value); }
        }

        public ICommand LoadDataCommand { get; private set; }
        public ICommand AddRouteCommand { get; private set; }
        public ICommand SelectRouteCommand { get; private set; }
        public ICommand DeleteRouteCommand { get; private set; }
        public ICommand CallRouteCommand { get; private set; }

        public RoutesPageViewModel(IRouteStore routeStore, IPageService pageService)
        {
            _routeStore = routeStore;
            _pageService = pageService;

            LoadDataCommand = new Command(async () => await LoadData());
            AddRouteCommand = new Command(async () => await AddRoute());
            SelectRouteCommand = new Command<RouteViewModel>(async c => await SelectRoute(c));
        }

        private async Task LoadData()
        {
            if (_isDataLoaded)
                return;

            _isDataLoaded = true;
            var routes = await _routeStore.GetRoutesAsync();
            foreach (var route in routes)
                Routes.Add(new RouteViewModel(route));
        }

        private async Task AddRoute()
        {
           // await _pageService.PushAsync(new RoutesDetailPage(new RouteViewModel()));
        }

        private async Task SelectRoute(RouteViewModel route)
        {
            if (route == null)
                return;

            SelectedRoute = null;
           // await _pageService.PushAsync(new RoutesDetailPage(route));
        }

    }
```

The property in the viewmodels are being set like this:
private string _roName;

```
    public string ROName
    {
        get { return _roName; }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ref _roName, value);
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ROName));
        }
    }
```

The constructor:

```
public RouteViewModel(Route route)
{
           //other properties 
   ROName = route.ROName;

}
```

[image: When the app loads.]

Comment: "ListView doesn't display it." - what specifically do you mean?  Do you meant that the selected item isn't highlighted?  Or that the SelectedItem doesn't display at all?

Comment: I've added a screenshot. The rows are all empty.However if I select one, the data is available in the code behind. I want the bound property ROName to appear

Comment: does `RouteViewModel` have a public property named `ROName`?

Comment: also, make `Label` a child of `ViewCell`, you shouldn't need `ViewCell.View`

Comment: the properties are there. I've added the RouteViewModel constructor / getter/setter for ROName.

Comment: what happens if you hardcode a value in the Label instead of using a binding?

Comment: You need to set Binding Context. Type in constructor: this.BindingContext = ViewModel;

Comment: @woj he is already doing that in `ViewModel` property

Comment: Does the text show if you hardcode a value in label?

Comment: Can you please add a breakpoint at LoadData method and check if the data has been added to Routes? Does the property ROName has a value? Through the screenshot, it looks like there is no data there.

Comment: I moved the LoadData to the constructor and verified the data is there before loading the view. I also downloaded and run the original project from the example, and it's not working, so I think there is something missing with the original example that I followed.

Comment: No, I download the example yesterday and it all works well on my side. Can you try to run another simulator, delete bin/obj folder and clean/rebuild your solution?

Comment: my environment must have been pooched. I scrapped it, pulled down the project again, and the data displays. Thanks for all your help. Apologies for wasting some of your time